# How to create a non-stackable widget grid?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, grid, widget

There are a lot of jQuery plugins to create grids where we can place widgets inside :
- gridster
- gridly
- maybe others ?

All of them are stacking the widgets either horizontally or vertically.
What I want to do is to have a 'free grid' where I can place widgets independently.

To have a better understanding, here are some 'drawings' :

```
[x]: occupied grid slot
[ ]: empty grid slot
```

This is what plugins like gridster and gridly are doing.
They are stacking vertically, placing something like the [o] is not possible because there is nothing under.

```
[x][x][x][ ]
[x][ ][x][ ]
[ ][ ][x][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][o]
```

What I want to do.
Here we can place items where we want.

```
[ ][ ][x][ ]
[ ][x][ ][x]
[ ][ ][ ][x]
[x][ ][x][ ]
```

What is the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who are searching an angular module to achieve that there is the great [angular-gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster) which is based on the gridster jQuery plugin.
Very configurable and works perfectly.